# Real-world portability of equal-rank unsigned to signed conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, portability, signed

Take the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char i = 128;
    signed char j = i;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(j) << '\n';
}
```

compiling on GCC, this produces `-128` as most programmers would naturally expect (when assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is a safe assumption in 2019). Now, I am fully aware that the initialisation `signed char j = i;` invokes implementation-defined behaviour in C++ standards before C++20.

**My question**: Realistically speaking, does anybody know of a semi-interesting compiler implementation of C++ that does not just *do the obvious thing* (i.e. a no-op in the above case). By semi-interesting, I mean compilers I can realistically encounter, not some prototype Unisys C++ compiler from 1985 for an obscure 43-bit architecture that only the DoD has access to. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) and [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/demotion-of-integers?view=vs-2019) document the above behaviour in its documentation, [Clang doesn't](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11272), but the observable behaviour is the same. My feeling is that there are none, and that this conversion, while formally implementation-defined behaviour, is portable in practice.

Comment: I think this is actually the wrong question.   Any compiler that targets a CPU architecture that uses ones-complement will have to use ones-complement.   There are certainly real-world CPUs, being actively maintained, that use ones-complement (e.g. unisys Dorado) and other CPUs (like Intel) that still support ones-complement (while providing other instructions related to two's complement).   All it needs is one customer to desire a C++ compiler that targets a ones-complement machine, and a vendor willing to implement it, and your assertion will become false.  Whether it is true now, or not.

Comment: My assertion is formally false already. I don't care that it is false. I care whether I'll have problems with the pattern in practice. Can you give an example of a C++17 compiler that produces different behaviour on an Intel ones-complement machine?

Comment: @JonasMüller Running your code on the online available GCC, CLang zapcc and MSVC compilers, old and new versions as available, they all give -128. I haven't encountered anything else in the wild than those mentioned in a long time.

Comment: Why would you not just write the trivial portable expression and let the compiler optimize it?

Comment: @stark What do you mean by the "trivial portable expression"? I'm not aware of a trivially portable expression that assigns 128 to a signed char without invoking implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @JonasMüller: Presumably `u>127 ? u-256 : u`, which [does get optimized](https://www.godbolt.org/z/UNUI2t).

Comment: @DavisHerring how do you do that in the case of `long long`/`int64_t`?

Comment: @JonasMüller: You subtract, cast, and subtract again: [also optimized](https://www.godbolt.org/z/BbOqs5).